# Removing annoying checkbox padding at android 4.1.2+

Tags: java, android, checkbox, padding

I got a problem with padding of checkbox to the next element (editview) within a gridlayout - how can i get rid of the extra space in here (see green marker in my picture)?

I tried to create a custom checkbox class and overwrite getCompoundPadingLeft, tried layout_marginRight="0", paddingRight="0", paddingLeft="0", ...
nothing worked.

The only thing which worked, was negative margin layout_marginRight="-10dp". But this is getting a problem on two different devices. Where the editview is close to the checkbox on device 1 (Samsung Galaxy S2), it is inside the checkbox on device 2 (LG G2).

Any ideas?

Screenshot:
[image]

Code:

```
        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                            <!-- ... -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:text="Zone1" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:checked="true"
                android:tag="110"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:width="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:numeric="integer"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:text="20" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:checked="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:width="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:numeric="integer"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:text="14" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:checked="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="6"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:width="50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:numeric="integer"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:text="8" />
```